Convert to BigInteger
I want to rewrite this function code to BigInteger class in Java:
 static int power(int x, int y, int p)
    {
        int res = 1; // Initialize result
 
        while (y > 0) {
 
            // If y is odd, multiply x with result
            if ((y & 1) != 0)
                res = res * x;
 
            // y must be even now
            y = y >> 1; // y = y/2
            x = x * x; // Change x to x^2
        }
        return res % p;
    }

I tried and wrote the following code:
static BigInteger power(BigInteger x, BigInteger y, BigInteger p) {
        BigInteger res = BigInteger.ONE; // Initialize result

        while (y.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1) {   

            // If y is odd, multiply x with result
            if ((y.and(BigInteger.ONE)) != BigInteger.ZERO)  
                res = res.multiply(x);  

            // y must be even now
            y = y.shiftRight(1); // y = y/2   
            x = x.multiply(x); // Change x to x^2
        }
        return res.mod(p);
    }

But when I tested input "power(2, 5, 13)", the output was 11, however, the correct answer is 6.
I checked the code I wrote several times, but couldn't find the problem. Can you please help me to output the correct answer code?

The whole point of calculating the power using modulo arithmetic is to avoid getting enormous intermediate results. For example, 999999^999999 would create a BigInteger that's too big to fit in your computer's memory, but you can calculate 999999^999999 mod 100 without using much memory. If you need modulo arithmetic, use BigInteger.modPow as per Elliott Frisch's answer.

You should compare reference types with .equals, not == as for primitives.
if (!BigInteger.ZERO.equals(y.and(BigInteger.ONE)))

In addition, you should only consider the sign of the result of compareTo; do not directly compare to a fixed value like 1.
while (y.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0)


Working demo

Shorter way: if (y.testBit(0) != 0)

That method is already implemented as BigInteger.modPow(BigInteger, BigInteger). I would call that, like
static BigInteger power(BigInteger x, BigInteger y, BigInteger p) {
    return x.modPow(y, p);
}

Second, you can't invoke the method with three int values. You need BigInteger arguments. Like,
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(power(BigInteger.valueOf(2),
            BigInteger.valueOf(5),
            BigInteger.valueOf(13)));
}

And I get
6


This should be the accepted answer, because there is a good reason that modPow exists. See my comment to the question.
